# Subgraph on hosted service issue with selecting based on an ethereum address

Tags: graphql, ethereum, subgraph, thegraph, thegraph.com

I have created  the schema for my subgraph inside the .graphql file, here is a sample:
`

```
type Post @entity {
  id: ID!
  title: String! # string
  body: String! # string
  createdAt: BigInt! # uint256
  groupID: BigInt! # uint256
}

type User @entity {
  id: ID! 
  userId: BigInt!
  transactionHash: Bytes
  telephoneVerifiedData: String
  email: String # string
  _userAddress: Bytes
}
```

`

I tried making a schema for the query treating _userAddress field as a plain text (I don't know any other way, can't find anything in the docs):

```
type _Schema_
  @fulltext(
    name: "getUser"
    language: simple
    algorithm: rank
    include: [
      { entity: "User", fields: [{ name: "userName", name: "_userAddress" }] }
    ]
  )
```

but I get this message when deploying the subgraph:

```
✖ Failed to deploy to Graph node https://api.thegraph.com/deploy/: deployment failure::subgraph validation error: [schema validation failed: [FulltextIncludedFieldInvalid("_userAddress")]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues.

In the fulltext query you specify `userName` as a field to search but it isn't defined on your `User` entity. Add `userName: String` to your `User` entity and

Second, the type of `_userAddress` is `Bytes`. In order for this field to be search it needs to be of type `String`.